# FINDSTR: help understanding results. Returns nothing, but no error when there is one expected?

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, command-prompt, findstr

I am writing a batch file. part of the program will compare the list of files in a 'source' folder. With the contents of a list in a text file.

I loop through each file in the folder, and search for its filename in the text file using FINDSTR

Everything works until there is a filename in the source folder that doesnt exist in the text file.

the findstr code:

```
for /f %%o in ('findstr %name% old.txt') do (
    echo o=%%o >> result.txt
    if %%o==%name% (
        echo %name% exists
    ) ELSE (
        echo %name% does not exists
    )
)
```

Again, the problem occurs when FINDSTR searches for a filename that is not in the text file.

when it reaches that point it outputs the variable %%o as being '%o' and echos nothing. So it sends nothing to the results.txt.

This doesnt trigger an ERRORLEVEL change but also will not echo anything. I have tried outputing the errorlevels but they are also empty. I just dont understand what FINDSTR is doing in this instance.

the FULL batch file: (its my first one. forgive any mistakes)

```
  ::return the raw (/b) list of files 
  FORFILES /p %~dp0source\ /s /m "*.cr2" /C "cmd /c echo @path" > new.txt

  ::pull file path for each file and send to subroutine
  for /f %%n in ('FORFILES /p %~dp0source\ /s /m "*.cr2" /C "cmd /c echo @path"') do (

    call :dequote %%n

  )

::subroutine for removing quotes 
::and returning the filename, extension, and path
:dequote
set fullPath=%~f1
set fileName=%~n1
set fileExt=%~x1
set filePath=%~dp1
set name=%fileName%& set npath=%filePath%& set ext=%fileExt%& set fpath=%fullPath%
echo %fpath%
echo %npath%
echo %name%
echo %ext%

for /f %%o in ('findstr %name% old.txt') do (
    echo o=%%o >> result.txt
    if %%o==%name% (
        echo %name% exists
    ) ELSE (
    echo %name% does not exists
    )
)
```

This only happens on the last filename sent to findstr. Any suggestions or direction would be very appreciated. Ive tried and read everything I can get my hands on.

Thank You for your time.

---

UPDATE: 9-9-15

Here is the working final batch file i created using the help on this page. It creates a hotfolder that will edit any new files added to it until you stop the script from running:

```
  :start

  :: return the raw (/b) list of files and full path to source text
  FORFILES /p %~dp0source\ /s /m "*.cr2" /C "cmd /c echo @path" > source.txt
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto :start

  ::join new and old data, return only what is shared in common (/g)
  findstr /I /L /G:"source.txt" "output.txt" > found.txt
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 copy /y source.txt notFound.txt

  ::join found file names and source filenames, return those that do not have a match
  findstr /I /L /V /G:"found.txt" "source.txt" >> notFound.txt
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 echo error no match

  ::for each line of notFound.txt, dequote and break apart
  for /f %%n in (notFound.txt) do (
    echo n=%%n
    call :dequote %%n
  )

  :dequote
  set fullPath=%~f1
  set fileName=%~n1
  set fileExt=%~x1
  set filePath=%~dp1
  set name=%fileName%& set npath=%filePath%& set ext=%fileExt%& set fpath=%fullPath%
  echo %fpath%
  echo %npath%
  echo %name%
  echo %ext%

  cd %nPath%
  if NOT [%1]==[] (
    echo converted %name%
    convert -negate -density 600 -colorspace gray flatField.cr2 %name%%ext% -compose Divide -composite %name%.tif
    move %name%.tif %~dp0output
    cd %~dp0
    del notFound.txt
    copy /y source.txt output.txt
    ) ELSE (
     echo end of batch else
     cd %~dp0
  )
```

Comment: The reason you aren't seeing the error level change is that the return value of `mycommand` in `for /F ('mycommand')` is always discarded.  It isn't specific to `findstr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop variables must be referenced with `%%` in a batch file because percent sign has a special meaning and must be therefore escaped with another percent sign in a batch file to specify it literally. This is the reason why on running the batch file with `echo on` in a command prompt window results in getting `%%o` in the batch file displayed as `%o` on execution.

Command **FOR** as used in

```
for /f %%o in ('findstr %name% old.txt') do
```

processes the output written to **stdout** by the called command `findstr`. But `findstr` does not write anything to standard output when it searched for one or more strings in a file and could not find any matching string in any line of the file.

So command **for** can't process anything and therefore none of the commands after `do` are processed at all in this case.

**Assuming the list file contains only file names without path**, the following commented batch file can be used to get with 1 execution of command **dir** and just 1 or 2 executions of console application **findstr** the two lists containing the file names in folder being found and being not found in the list file. The batch file is written for not producing empty files.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ListFile=C:\Temp\List.txt"
if not exist "%ListFile%" goto NoListFile

set "SourceFolder=C:\Temp\Test"
if not exist "%SourceFolder%\*" goto NoSourceFolder

set "AllFileNames=%TEMP%\AllFileNames.txt"
set "FoundFileNames=%TEMP%\FoundFileNames.txt"
set "NotFoundFileNames=%TEMP%\NotFoundFileNames.txt"

rem Get alphabetic list of files in source folder without path.
dir /A /B /ON "%SourceFolder%" >"%AllFileNames%"

rem Find all file names in list file with a case-insensitive
rem search matching completely a file name in list file and
rem output the found file names to another list file.
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /L /X "/G:%AllFileNames%" "%ListFile%" >"%FoundFileNames%"
if errorlevel 1 goto NoFileNameFound

rem Find all file names with a case-insensitive search found
rem before in all file names list and output the lines not
rem containing one of the file names to one more list file.
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /L /V "/G:%FoundFileNames%" "%AllFileNames%" >"%NotFoundFileNames%"
if errorlevel 1 goto AllFileNamesFound

rem Some file names are found in list file and others not.
del "%AllFileNames%"
goto :EndBatch

:NoFileNameFound
move /Y "%AllFileNames%" "%NotFoundFileNames%"
del "%FoundFileNames%"
goto EndBatch

:AllFileNamesFound
del "%AllFileNames%"
del "%NotFoundFileNames%"
goto EndBatch

:NoListFile
echo %~f0:
echo Error: No list file %ListFile%
goto EndBatch

:NoSourceFolder
echo %~f0:
echo Error: No folder %SourceFolder%

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: this was incredibly helpful. I was able to follow your comments well and devise a batch file that accomplishes what i needed. I will update my final code above. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to give you a list of filenames which don't exist in the `file.txt`

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\folder\to\check"
for %%a in (*) do findstr /i "%%~nxa" "file.txt" >nul || echo "%%a" is missing
pause
```

It uses `%%~nxa` instead of `%%a` in case subdirectories are used at some point.